Can I use my passport with a small cut on the biodata?
I would like to ask if a minor cut on biodata of passport is still acceptable or not. This was damaged by a visa stamp at an embassy.


As a general rule, any damage to that page is likely unacceptable.

I have already went home with a passport in much more worse state and no one has even recognized. Although it was in the covid years.

It is entirely possible (or even likely) that this passport could be used without objection for the passport-holder to return to the country that issued the passport.

If it was a rip on the edge only it might still be OK, but anything affecting the ID photo is very risky. I would get a replacement passport.

Is this page the thicker/plastic one that contains the chip with biometric data? If so,the cut may well have severed the wires forming the antenna,making the chip unusable. That would mean severe damage certainly requiring replacement.

Using this passport will be a gamble.  Many of the people who need to look at, check-in clerks and immigration officers, might not notice or care but you just need one strict one to cause a big problem: maybe not allowed on a flight or, worse still, refused entry on arrival.
Even if your embassy says that it is okay, others will not be obliged to agree.  The opinions of random strangers on the Internet will be even less effective.
A colleague had a suspicious crease on his photo page (long ago when your ID photo was laminated onto the info page).  A UK immigration officer thought that it had been tampered with; it had not, it had been issued that way.  He was allowed to phone me.  I had to drive to the airport and vouch for him.  Obviously, that particular problem won't occur today but it illustrates that some immigration officers are stricter than others.

Was that before biometric passports? Today they can, in theory, pull the photo up from the chip and verify the cryptographic signature from the issuer. Of course, that assumes governments have their border IT straight.

Yes before biometric passports.  My point was not that that specific problem might occur today but that some people who need to see your passport might be unusually strict.  His passport had been accepted by many others e.g. when he checked in for the flight.

There's a big difference between a mutilated and damaged passport. Looks like yours falls under "damaged" rather than "mutilated." Mutilated means you intentionally changed it somehow, while damaged means something accidental happened, like water or a rip.
Definitely worth checking with your local embassy or consulate though. They can tell you for sure if it needs to be replaced or not. If it's damaged/mutilated, you might need an Affidavit from a Notary, like this info explains: https://losangelespcg.org/lost-or-damaged-epassport/

The decision whether to accept the passport or not is made by airline staff and the destination country's immigration officials, not your own embassy. I don't think a notarized statement would help much here.
